# react - how to show relevant element when click button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component that renders jsx like this

```
<section>

    <div>
        <input type="text" class="hide" />
        <button id={item.uniqueID}>show input</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" class="hide" />
        <button id={item.uniqueID}>show input</button>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" class="hide" />
        <button id={item.uniqueID}>show input</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

I want this behavior, when I click the button in the first div, the input in the first div will show. Similarly, I click the button in the third div the input in third div will show.

How you do that in react?

Comment: It should be className

Comment: I use attribute transforms plugin in webpack, so I can use class instead of className

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me I would make a new component out of:

show input

Lets call it `<InputToggler/>`

and then it would have a state of inputHidden for its own input and use classes to determine if it should show or not and the button would have an onclick handler to toggle the state of hidden or shown. Here is a pen showing exactly that

http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/VKPXoN

```
class InputToggler extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      inputHidden: true
    }
  }

  toggleInput = () => {
    this.setState({
      inputHidden: !this.state.inputHidden
    })
  };

  render() {
    const inputClass = this.state.inputHidden ? 'hide' : '';
    const buttonLabel = this.state.inputHidden ? 'show input' : 'hide input'
    return (
      <span>
        <input type="text" className={inputClass} />
        <button onClick={this.toggleInput} id={this.props.item.uniqueID}>          
          {buttonLabel}
        </button>
      </span>
     )
  }
}
```

Comment: I have 3 dynamic inputs, not just one. Can you show how you do it with dynamic elements?

Comment: @angry_kiwi then render InputToggler 3 times. That's half of the reason for React components, they are reusable.

Comment: What @MatisLepik said, by extracting it into its own component not only can you reuse it here three times but anywhere else in the app, and it takes care of its own internal state. You just have to pass item in as a prop as shown in the codepen. If you had an items array and wanted each item to have an input you would do something like `items.map(function(item, index) { return <InputToggler item={item} key={index} /> })` and that would return an array of InputToggler components each with its own state.

Comment: I have updated http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/VKPXoN to include this, using an items array and generating three inputs

Comment: ok, what if the button have be outside of divs, therefore it can not be inside inputToggler component? I updated my jsx to reflect this situation. How would solve this one?

Comment: I would want to know why it can't be within the same container. You can always wrap them both in a span and have the input be within its own div. There would be no logical reason for you to try and decouple them from each other when one is directly influencing the other. But I did make it owrk that way in my pen so you could see http://codepen.io/finalfreq/pen/VKPXoN

Comment: @finalfreq solution is good. Otherwise if you wrap them inside your container, you will have to identify who was clicked when onClick is triggered and whom to hide. That is a lot of unnecessary logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is the concept not the exact code.

Each button should have onClick with callback to a function ex. toggleShow

```
<button id={item.uniqueID} onClick={this.toggleShow.bind(this)}>show input</button>
```

toggleShow do something like:

```
toggleShow(e){
    var item = e.target.id;
    this.setState({inputClassName1: "hide"})
```

at the same time the input field classname should refer to the state

Note that I omitted the fact that you have multiple objects, you may want to handle their references in arrays.